# Python regex to remove emails from string

Tags: python, regex

Need to replace emails in a string, so:

```
inp = 'abc user@xxx.com 123 any@www foo @ bar 78@ppp @5555 aa@111"
```

should result in:

```
out = 'abc 123 foo bar"
```

What regex to use?

```
In [148]: e = '[^\@]\@[^\@]'
In [149]: pattern = re.compile(e)
In [150]: pattern.sub('', s)  
Out[150]: 'one aom 123 4two'
In [151]: s
Out[151]: 'one ab@com 123 4 @ two'
```

Does not work for me

Comment: I would suggest splitting the string on whitespaces, removing the elements of the array containing an @ and merging the string. But it is not a regex

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using a regular expression to validate an email address](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/201323/using-a-regular-expression-to-validate-an-email-address)

Comment: @fonfonx Yes, I was thinking about splitting, removing and merging back also. But it seems overkill to me.

Comment: actually example in question is wrong,
any@www  78@ppp @5555 are not valid email and so they should not be removed.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Replace :
`\S*@\S*\s?`
by ''
Demo [here](https://regex101.com/r/J0ohIf/1)
**Some explanations :**
`\S*` : match as many non-space characters you can
`@` : then a @
`\S*` : then another sequence of non-space characters
`\s?` : And eventually a space, if there is one. Note that the '?' is needed to match an address at the end of the line. Because of the greediness of '?', if there is a space, it will always be matched.

Comment: My mistake, it works, thanks! Why trailing '\s?' is needed?

Comment: @dokondr: It's just that if you use only `\S*@\S*`, your remaining words will be separated by more than one space if an address has been deleted between them. By adding `\s?`, each time you delete an address, you will delete one space with it

Comment: I have added explanations. Tell me if you do not understand something

Answer (score 4):

Adding as nobody as added a regex :

```
text= 'abc user@xxx.com 123 any@www foo @ bar 78@ppp @5555 aa@111'

required_output=re.sub(r'[A-Za-z0-9]*@[A-Za-z]*\.?[A-Za-z0-9]*', "", text)
    
required_output=" ".join(required_output.split())
```

Answer (score 3):

I personally prefer doing string parsing myself. Let's try splitting the string and getting rid of the items that have the `@` symbol:

```
inp = 'abc user@xxx.com 123 any@www foo @ bar 78@ppp @5555 aa@111'
items = inp.split()
```

Now we can do something like this:

```
>>> [i for i in items if '@' not in i]
['abc', '123', 'foo', 'bar']
```

That gets us almost there. Let's modify it a bit more to add a `join`:

```
>>> ' '.join([i for i in inp.split() if '@' not in i])
'abc 123 foo bar'
```

It may not be RegEx, but it works for the input you gave.

Comment: actually example in question is wrong,
any@www  78@ppp @5555 are not valid email and so they should be removed.

Answer (score 1):

```
out = ' '.join([item for item in inp.split() if '@' not in item])
```

Answer (score 0):

In case somebody needs to remove e-mail addresses that include hyphens or dots such as *joanne-doe@pm.me* or *joanne-doe@pm.me*. Below an amended solution based on what TBhavnani suggested that removes these too.

```
import re

text = ['joanne-doe@pm.me is my e-mail','My e-mail is joanne.doe@pm.me']

for line in text:
        line = line.strip()
        line = re.sub(r'\w*(?:[\.\-]\w+)@[A-Za-z]*\.?[A-Za-z0-9]*', "", line)       
        print(line)
```

**Gives following output:**

```
 is my e-mail
My e-mail is
```